# How to find out if any of the remaining numbers in a list are greater than another

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, numbers

Looking for a little help with something if someone could help me out, not looking for someone to do it for me just to point me in the right direction.
Basically I have created a list of numbers, high prices for each day for the last month.  Starting with the first day I want to know if the high of this day has been breached any other day of the month GOING FORWARD. If it has I have no use for this number however if it hasn't I need to save it to use later  Then do the same for the second day etc.

So far I am using a for loop, it's not finished as you can see but I can add a Map to it later, right now i'm just looking for what I have to replace the bold part with so that it looks at all the remaining days and not just the follwing one.

```
      for( i = 0; i < highs.size(); i++){
      if(highs(i) > **highs(i+1**)) {
      console.getOut().println(highs[i]);

      }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Consider adding a second inner loop on a variable `j` from `i+1` to `highs.size()`. You also want to limit `i` to `highs.size() - 1`(otherwise `highs.get(i+1)` is illegal). Then you can use the indices `i` and `j`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help Elliot, the adding of a second loop worked perfectly for what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to keep the largest number in the high list.
Iterating over the list, compare the current number(A) with next number(B), and swap in case A>B. By iterating over the list of size "n", n-1 times, since we only need to make n-1 comparisons, you will get the largest number at the last index.

```
for(i=0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
        //swapping if num is greater than the next number.
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = tmp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Vartika thanks for you input, i'm very new with Java and hadn't come across Iterator function before, I managed to get it work with the addition of a second loop though.   I may not have fully understood your advice but It looks at first glance like this technique would give the highest number in the entire list?  I'm actually looking to only return a particular number if it hasn't been exceeded from it's respective day to the end of the list, what happened prior to each day would be irrelevant.  Is this something the itertor function can do?